# jQuery search using data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I'm trying to search for items using the `data-find` attribute but my function is just matching the input string with any text inside of the container.

You can see this by adding words to the HTML and then entering the input.

How do I get my function to match what's in the `data-find` attribute?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-text").keyup(function() {
    var n = $("#search-text").val(),
        t = ($(".item").attr("[data-find]"),
             n.replace(/ /g, "'):finditem('"));
    $.extend($.expr[":"], {
      finditem: function(n, t, e, i) {
        return (
          (n.textContent || n.inText || "")
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf((e[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0
        );
      }
    }),
      $("#subcat-list div")
      .not(":finditem('" + t + "')")
      .each(function(n) {
      $(this).removeClass("subcat-item");
    }),
      $("#subcat-list div:finditem('" + t + "')").each(function(n) {
      $(this).addClass("subcat-item");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#subcat-list {
  display: flex;
}
.subcat-item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-text" placeholder="search">

<div id="subcat-list">
  <div class="subcat-item" style="background:red">
    <div class="item" data-find="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcat-item blue" style="background:blue">
    <div class="item" data-find="blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcat-item green" style="background:green">
    <div class="item" data-find="green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks way more complicated for the requirement you specified - `search for items using the data-find attribute`. Please share some sample inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `each`, `toggleClass` and `includes`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-text").keyup(function() {
    var n = $("#search-text").val().toLowerCase(); //convert value to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison
    $(".item").each( function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       var value = $this.attr( "data-find" ).toLowerCase(); //convert attribute value to lowercase
       $this.parent().toggleClass( "hidden", !value.includes( n ) );
    })
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-text").keyup(function() {
    var n = $("#search-text").val();
    $(".item").each( function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       var value = $this.attr( "data-find" ).toLowerCase();
       $this.parent().toggleClass( "hidden", !value.includes( n ) );
    })
  });
});
```

```css
#subcat-list {
  display: flex;
}
.subcat-item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-text" placeholder="search">

<div id="subcat-list">
  <div class="subcat-item" style="background:red">
    <div class="item" data-find="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcat-item blue" style="background:blue">
    <div class="item" data-find="blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcat-item green" style="background:green">
    <div class="item" data-find="green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I modify this so that instead of `.parent()` it calls to the class name directly? My web platform adds a second class to `.sub-cat-item` (for dynamic data) so I need to call it directly in order to show/hide the div

Comment: Instead of `$this.parent()`, say `$this.closest(".sub-cat-item")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` to show and hide the divs depending on the `data`

using `.includes` you can check weather a `data-find` contains the characters of the value if the textbox

```js
$(function() {
  $("#search-text").keyup(function() {
    var n = $(this).val(); /* Get the value of the textbox */
    $(".subcat-item").show(); /* Show all .subcat-item */
    $(".item").filter(function() { /* Filter all .item and hide*/
      return !$(this).data('find').includes(n);
    }).parent().hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#subcat-list {
  display: flex;
}

.subcat-item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-text" placeholder="search">

<div id="subcat-list">
  <div class="subcat-item" style="background:red">
    <div class="item" data-find="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcat-item blue" style="background:blue">
    <div class="item" data-find="blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="subcat-item green" style="background:green">
    <div class="item" data-find="green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a simple [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
$(".item[data-find*='" + n + "']")
```

will search for `.item` whose `data-find` contains the value of `n`.

Comment: The search is supposed to take what's entered into the input and match it with the `data-find` attributes of the items. So I can't specify anything in the JS because it's input depending

Comment: You don't know how to put a variable into a string?